# Where does the Buddha describe suffering as being like a person who is hit by two arrows?

Tags: reference-request, wisdom

The attached discourse was delivered a few days back from New York and presents a very comprehensive approach to face the corona pandemic from a spiritual standpoint. The wisdom of the Buddha is quoted at the very beginning and the entire discourse is structured on this quote. It would be appreciated if someone could source the original sutta from which this quotation is made.

[Fighting Anxiety and Depression: Four Great Practices](https://youtu.be/vzFtOOVQPmA?t=255)

> Buddha speaks of the nature of suffering as a person who is hit by an arrow.
>   Imagine the pain and the shock of being hit by an arrow.
>   And immediately after that, this person, unfortunate person is hit by a second arrow.

Comment: https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn36/sn36.006.than.html probably this

Comment: @116PУC Please post that as an answer instead of as a comment -- https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1589/254

Comment: Not enough symbols to be posted as an answer

Answer (score 4):

Probably this: [Sallatha Sutta: The Arrow (SN 36.6)](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn36/sn36.006.than.html)

> The Blessed One said, "When touched with a feeling of pain, the uninstructed run-of-the-mill person sorrows, grieves, & laments, beats his breast, becomes distraught. So he feels two pains, physical & mental. Just as if they were to shoot a man with an arrow and, right afterward, were to shoot him with another one, so that he would feel the pains of two arrows; in the same way, when touched with a feeling of pain, the uninstructed run-of-the-mill person sorrows, grieves, & laments, beats his breast, becomes distraught. So he feels two pains, physical & mental.
>
> As he is touched by that painful feeling, he is resistant. Any resistance-obsession [etc.]